# How to load classpath @PropertySource inside a jar?

Tags: java, spring

- I am using spring-context 5.3.13 (no spring-boot)
- I have a file named "config.yaml" under "src/main/resources"
- I have this @PropertySource configured: `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config.yaml", factory = TypesafeAdapterPropertySourceFactory.class)`
- When I run it from intellij it successfully loads the file

My issue:
When running a jar the file is not found due to the path being unavailable inside the jar.
More info:

- the file itself is inside the jar root (checked it)
- Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.viber.httpmsexample.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.yaml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/C:/Repositories/http-ms-example/target/app.jar!/config.yaml
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
> at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
> at com.mytest.httpmsexample.Application.main(Application.java:63)
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.yaml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/C:/Repositories/http-ms-example/target/app.jar!/config.yaml
> at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217)
> at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:162)
> at com.mytest.libraries.anticorruption.config.TypesafeAdapterPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(TypesafeAdapterPropertySourceFactory.java:14)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:463)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:280)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207)
> at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175)
> ... 8 more

I can externalize this config but I wish to keep it there for now.
Is it possible to get over that issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `TypesafeAdapterPropertySourceFactory`?

Comment: The problem is your own `TypesafeAdapterPropertySourceFactory` which tries to create the property source based on a `File` which doesn't work when the file is in a jar. A `File` in the sense of java is a physical file on the filesystem, one that is inside an archive isn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum this was the issue, thanks!
Do you want to put up an answer and I will mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your own `TypesafeAdapterPropertySourceFactory` which tries to create the property source based on a `File` which doesn't work when the file is in a jar. A File in the sense of java is a physical file on the filesystem, one that is inside an archive isn't.

I would strongly suggest to use the `ResourcePropertySource` to create the property source and decorate that instead of something else.